# Not able to set the cornerRadius of a UIButton That has been Created Programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift4

I am trying to set the `cornerRadius` of a `UIButton` so that it looks like circular , but I am not able to do it .

Here is the code for what I have tried.

```
func addColorButton() {
    let colorButton : UIButton = {
        let cb = UIButton()
        cb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cb.backgroundColor = .black

        return cb
    }()

    view.addSubview(colorButton)
    colorButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    colorButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    colorButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
    colorButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
    colorButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * colorButton.bounds.size.width
    print(colorButton.bounds.width)
    colorButton.clipsToBounds = true

}
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   addColorButton()
}
```

Comment: The button's bounds won't be set until after autolayout has completed.  Set the radius in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: When I print the colorbutton.bounds.size.width it is showing 0.0

Comment: so what changes you suggest for that Paulw11

Comment: put this (`colorButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * colorButton.bounds.size.width`) line in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Yeah its working thanks Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buttons bounds/frame won't set until autolayout completed.
You could update,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() 

    // Update corner radius here
    colorButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * colorButton.bounds.size.width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use masksToBounds for this.

```
colorButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple subclass which can use whenever you need

I just show reference of UIButton with shadow and round corner , You can make it IBInspectable to use these properties from storyboard though .

```
class UIButtonShadow: UIButton {


var yPos : CGFloat = 2 {
    didSet {
        addBehavior()
    }
}

var radius : CGFloat = 2 {
    didSet {
        addBehavior()
    }
}

var cornerRadius : CGFloat = 18 {
    didSet {
        addBehavior()
    }
}


override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        addBehavior()
    }
}

override var frame: CGRect{
    didSet{
        addBehavior()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addBehavior()
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    addBehavior()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func addBehavior() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:self.bounds,cornerRadius:self.layer.cornerRadius)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0.0,height:yPos)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
}
}
```